# In SSRS RDL toggle button expand/collapse making report slower due to huge data

Tags: ssrs-2012, rdl

I am using toggle button expand/collapse button to call subreport in my RDL I am facing time out error because every time if I load or click on view report button it is checking the subreport stored procedure if 2000 rows the report is checking for 2000 rows. Is there any way that it should stop calling subreport stored procedure and while I press on expand button then only it should call subreport stored procedure.

I tried in visibility by giving a expression `IIF(isnothing(field!value))` but it did not work either. It is taking 2 minutes 40 seconds to load the report.